# Rotating around arbitrary point, not center when using Google Earth Pro to Edit Image Overlay?

Tags: georeferencing, google-earth, overlay, rotate

In Google Earth Pro "Edit Image Overlay", we can rotate the overlay
around its center (via grabbing the green diamond,) but how might one
rotate it around an arbitrary point not its center?

(Yes, doing so would just be a shortcut for a rotation around its
center combined with a translation (grabbing the "+" at the center and
moving it.))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image overlay positioning tools in Google Earth Pro are rather basic. While they let you do a lot of things, rotating the image around a point that's not the center is not one of those things.  In order to do that, you'll need to bring the image into software with more advanced geo-referencing tools.  I've used QGIS to do things like this, and I'm guessing ArcGIS could do it too.

Comment: Indeed, even for the rotation it does provide, one needs to zoom out until the "diamond" is within the screen to be able to grab it.